Quand est-ce qu'on écrit des sigles avec/sans points (ex. T.P. ou TP)
Quand est-ce qu'on écrit des sigles avec/sans points (ex. T.P. ou TP pour travaux pratiques).

Quand on trouve l'un ou l'autre plus pratique, et mettre les "." est casse-pieds, surtout sur un mobile ;-)

Les sigles s'écrivaient traditionnellement avec des points. La tendance actuelle est de ne plus mettre de points et la plupart des ouvrages ne recommandent pas leur utilisation.
Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale :

En ce qui concerne [l'écriture des sigles], la seule unification possible et applicable à tous les cas est l'emploi de lettres capitales sans points ; outre le cas de nombreux sigles de formation syllabique excluant la présence de points ceux qui pourraient en comporter n'en sont qu'inutilement et inesthétiquement allongés.

Robert :

Traditionnellement, les sigles issus d'une suite de mots français s'écrivent avec des points abréviatifs après chaque lettre, tandis que les sigles issus d'une suite de mots anglais s'écrivent plus souvent sans points (ADSL, DVD, SMS). Aujourd'hui, par souci de simplification, on écrit généralement tous les sigles sans points.

BDL :

Pour des raisons de simplification et d’uniformisation, il est préférable d’écrire les sigles sans points abréviatifs. Cet usage est reconnu dans les codes typographiques récents, et est pratiqué par les grandes maisons d’édition et la presse francophone. L’emploi des points reste évidemment correct.

Usito :

On ne laisse pas d’espace entre les lettres d’un sigle ou d’un acronyme et il est d’usage de ne pas mettre de point abréviatif entre les lettres.

Le seul ouvrage que j'ai pu consulter et qui recommande explicitement l'utilisation des points est Antidote.

Une tendance lourde de l’usage contemporain est de ne plus utiliser de points abréviatifs dans les sigles et acronymes : PIB, OPA, NIP, OTAN. Il est quand même acceptable, et même préférable, de les employer dans le cas particulier des sigles épelés pour signaler au lecteur leur prononciation alphabétique.

Un ngram sur T.P./TP, S.N.C.F./SNCF, U.N.I.C.E.F./UNICEF, O.G.M./OGM montre que l'écriture sans points est plus fréquente.

